# how to acces other class method in java

Tags: java, class, methods

I have two classes:

1. class actUI

> public class ActUI extends javax.swing.JFrame{
>
> //there are the other classes here
>
> ```
>       private static void writeToFile(java.util.List list, String path) {
>             BufferedWriter out = null;
>             try {
>                     File file = new File(path);
>                     out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
>                     for (Object s : list) {
>                             out.write((String) s); 
>                             out.newLine();
>
>                     }
>                     out.close();
>             } catch (IOException e) {
>             }
>         UniqueLineReader ULR  = new UniqueLineReader();
>         ULR.setFileName(path);
>     }
>
>   //there are the other classes here
>
> }
> ```

2. Class UniqueLineReader:

> public class UniqueLineReader extends BufferedReader {
>
> ```
> Set<String> lines = new HashSet<String>();
> private Reader arg0;
>
> public UniqueLineReader(Reader arg0) {
>     super(arg0);
> }
>
> @Override
> public String readLine() throws IOException {
>     String uniqueLine;
>     while (lines.add(uniqueLine = super.readLine()) == false); //read until encountering a unique line
>         return uniqueLine;
> }
>
> public void setFileName(String filePath){
>      try {
>         // Open the file that is the first
>         // command line parameter
>         FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("test.txt");
>         UniqueLineReader br = new UniqueLineReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
>         String strLine;
>         // Read File Line By Line
>         PrintWriter outFile2 = new PrintWriter(new File("result.txt"));
>         String result       = "";
>         List data = new ArrayList();
>         while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
>             // Print the content on the console
>             System.out.println(strLine);
>             data.add(strLine);
>         }
>         writeToFile(data, "result.txt");
>         // Close the input stream
>         //in.close();
>     } catch (Exception e) {// Catch exception if any
>         System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> }

I want to acces UniqueLineReader from writeToFile method in actUI, but my code is not working, how can i do that with no error?, help me please.

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Just a minute, you have two methods called `writeToFile()` in two different classes ? bad design buddy... refactor your code!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your code.

```
UniqueLineReader ULR = new UniqueLineReader(); // invalid constructor
ULR.setFileName(path);
```

There is no matching constructor for this. If you want to access `writeToFile()` from `ActUI`, Just change access modifier of `writeToFile()` to public now you can use following

```
UniqueLineReader.writeToFile(new ArrayList(), path);
```